# JavaFx2 ImageView with icon displays in Scenebuilder but does not display during runtime

Tags: javafx-2

In Scenebuilder I added an Imageview to a gridpane and selected an icon as a jpeg image. I stored the icon in My Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyProject.
It shows up fine in Scenebuilder however when I run the program, no icon shows.

In Scenebuilder 1.1 I added an Imageview to a gridpane and selected an icon as a jpeg image. I stored the icon in My Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyProject. It shows up fine in Scenebuilder however when I run the program, no icon shows.

Here is the tag in my fxml file

```
        <ImageView fitHeight="36.28910772144808" fitWidth="96.66667175292969" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0">
          <image>
            <Image url="@../../my_pic.JPG" />
          </image>
        </ImageView>
```

Windows XP, NetBeans 7.1, Java 7

Answer (score 1):

Put all your images in the "src" subdirectory of the project. And then choose them from the Scene Builder.
When you compile your project, the image files in the "src" subdirectory will be included into the jar-file.

Answer (score 0):

Scenebuilder is independent of NetBeans. One has to manually copy over the image files to the src/ folder before running.